# Don't have any idea how this works, KnockOutJS

Tags: knockout.js

I want to edit something in a site but i can't understand properly. I got this line

```
{{ Hooks::renderHtml('Titles.Index.ForEachMovie') }}
```

What i can't figure out is what **Titles.Index.ForEachMovie** is.
This renders a list of movies, and I want to filter this list, show just some of them.

Comment: What does your data-bind attribute looks like? So far this does not even look like knockouJS

Comment: data-bind="foreach: {data: sourceItems, afterRender: lazyLoadImage}"

Comment: You will have to filter sourceItems in your javascript model, most likely by using a knockoutJS computed function http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html. I also like to use underscoreJS to help with the filtering, it can do it in 1 line.

Comment: Where I can find sourceItems? I come from Python, PHP, and things like, frameworks and routes make me dizzy.

Comment: There is usually a js file, which contains a Model that is binded to the html page using data-bind attributes. In that JS file you will usually find a model with many properties, one of these will be "sourceItems"

Answer (score 0):

'Titles.Index.ForEachMovie' is a list coming from Backend I assume.

for now, lets say 'Titles.Index.ForEachMovie' would be like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ko.applyBindings({
        Titles.Index.ForEachMovie: [
            { movieName: 'Titanic', movieId: 1},
            { movieName: 'The Secret life of Pets',movieId: 2 },
            { movieName: 'The guardian',movieId: 3 }
        ]
    });
</script>
```

all you got to do is iterate through this list using "visible" binding :

```
<table>
    <thead>
         <tr>
          <th>Movie Name</th>
         </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: Titles.Index.ForEachMovie">
        <tr>

            <td data-bind="text: movieName",visible: movieId() == 2></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

or you can do something like this:

```
<table>
        <thead>
             <tr>
              <th>Movie Name</th>
             </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: Titles.Index.ForEachMovie">
            <tr>
             <!-- ko if:movieId() == 2 -->
                <td data-bind="text: movieName"></td>
            <!-- /ko -->
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```